# Iterate through json response and return one array

Tags: json, ruby

Code below returns me all counties as a string, I can see that by using inspect method.

```
def self.all_counties
    response['ChargeDevice'].each do |charger|
        puts ['ChargeDeviceLocation']['Address']['County'].inspect
    end
end
```

What would be the right way to store every returned string in one array so I can manipulate it later?

JSON

```
"ChargeDeviceLocation"   =>   {  
  "Latitude"      =>"51.605591",
  "Longitude"      =>"-0.339510",
  "Address"      =>      { 
     "County"         =>"Greater London",
     "Country"         =>"gb"
  }
```

Comment: Use `map` instead of `each` and store the result in a variable.

Comment: You may also find it helpful to use [`Hash#dig`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig) instead of repeated `[]` calls, to avoid `nil` errors.

Comment: i.e. `charger.dig('ChargeDeviceLocation', 'Address', 'County')`

Comment: My guess is that your example raises a `TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer` exception, because there is no `Address` index on the `['ChargeDeviceLocation']` array.

Comment: Oh, and obviously... *returns me all counties as a string* -- **what string**? If an API is returning the data as a string, then you can presumably convert it into array - but I can't tell you how, without knowing what the original string is!

Comment: I have tried to change each to map and when I do inspect I still see that string returned. Why is that?

Comment: *that string* -- **what string??**

Comment: is the string returned a list of comma separated values?

Comment: Tom Lord Please take a look at JSON in my updated question. I mean county: "Greater London"

Comment: What I want to do is to store every county to an array while iterating though hash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works if the response has all the keys for every item:

```
counties = response['ChargeDevice'].map do |r|
  r.dig('ChargeDeviceLocation', 'Address', 'County')
end
```

Something like this will give you nils when the tree doesn't have entries for all items:

```
counties = response['ChargeDevice'].map do |r|
  r.fetch('ChargeDeviceLocation', {}).
    fetch('Address', {}).
    fetch('County', nil)
end
```

You could also use [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) (and [ruby JSONPath gem](https://github.com/joshbuddy/jsonpath)).

```
require 'jsonpath'
counties = JsonPath.new('$..County').on(response.to_json)
```